# PHP code always setting file upload flag to set even if nothing is uploaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my HTML Code:

```
<form id="broadcastForm" onSubmit="return false;" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div>
    <label for="image">Select an Image to Broadcast (Optional) <span class="text-danger">[Make sure image size is less than 500Kb]</span></label>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" class="btn btn-primary" id="image" name="image[]" class="fileinput" style="margin-top: 10px;" />
    <div class="preview_box">
      <img id="preview_img" src=""/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <textarea class="textarea form-control" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter Message To Broadcast.." style="width: 100%; height: 125px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;"></textarea>
</form>
```

This is my JQuery code:

```
$("button#brodcastMessage").click(function()
    {
        var proceed = true, image = $("#image").val(), message = $("#message").val(), type = "", dataSend = "";
        var formData = new FormData();

        if(image == "" && message == "" || image == null && message == null)
            {
                proceed = false;
                swal({
                        title: "Error Sending Email!",
                        text: "To send Email Broadcast to your subscribers you need to either select an image or enter the broadcast message. Both the fields are blank!",
                        icon: "error",
                    });
            }

        else if(image == "" || image == null && message != "")
            {
                proceed = true;
                formData.append('message', message);
                formData.append('image', "");
            }

        else if(message == "" || message == null && image != "")
            {
                proceed = true;
                formData.append('image', $('#image')[0].files[0]);
            }

        else if(message != "" && image != "")
            {
                proceed = true;
                formData.append('message', message);
                formData.append('image', $('#image')[0].files[0]);
            }

        if(proceed)
            {
                $("button#brodcastMessage").addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', 'true').html("Sending Mail Please Wait...");

                $.ajax({
                            url: '/ajax?id=broadcast',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: formData,
                            cache: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            processData: false,
                            success:function(response)
                                {
                                    resp = response.slice(-3); //read last three characters of a string

                                    if(resp == "ack")
                                        {
                                            $("form#upload_form").trigger('reset');
                                            $("#image").val("");
                                            $('#preview_img').attr('src', '');
                                            $("button#brodcastMessage").removeClass('disabled').html('Send <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>').removeAttr('disabled');
                                            $("form#emailFormSend").trigger('reset');
                                            swal({
                                                    title: "Message Sent!",
                                                    icon: "success",
                                                });
                                        }
                                    else if(resp == "nak")
                                        {
                                            $("button#brodcastMessage").removeClass('disabled').html('Send <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>').removeAttr('disabled');
                                            swal({
                                                    title: "Error Sending Email!",
                                                    text: "Please Try Again!",
                                                    icon: "error",
                                                });
                                        }
                                    else
                                        {
                                            $("button#brodcastMessage").removeClass('disabled').html('Send <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>').removeAttr('disabled');
                                            swal({
                                                    title: "Error Log!",
                                                    text: response,
                                                    icon: "error",
                                                });
                                        }
                                },
                            error:function(response)
                                {
                                    $("button#brodcastMessage").removeClass('disabled').html('Send <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>').removeAttr('disabled');
                                    swal({
                                            title: "Network Error!",
                                            text: "There was an Error Processing your request! Please try again after some time!",
                                            icon: "error",
                                        });
                                }
                        });
            }
    });
```

This is my PHP Code:

```
if($_GET['id'] == "broadcast")
    {
        if($_POST['message'] == "" || $_POST['message'] == null && isset($_FILES) && !empty($_FILES))
            {
                //file variable is set
                $counter = "file";
            }

        if(isset($_FILES) && empty($_FILES) && $_POST['message'] != "" || $_POST['message'] != null)
            {
                //message varibale is set
                $counter = "message";
            }

        if(isset($_FILES) && !empty($_FILES) && $_POST['message'] != "" || $_POST['message'] != null)
            {
                //both are present
                $counter = "both";
            }

        echo $counter;
        exit();
    }
```

Hello, I am trying to do an ajax file upload. Now I am creating a broadcast message where I have provided 2 inputs

```
1.) Select image &
2.) Enter message
```

Now there can be 4 conditions

```
1.) Either both of them are blank (i have handled this on client side)
2.) Either I only want to broadcast message but not image
3.) Either I want to broadcast image but not message
4.) Either I want to broadcast both image and message
```

So i have set this on PHP and JQuery side validation the problem is that when there is message set and file note set then the php script gives and error of image is an undefined variable.

What my script is doing is even if file is not being uploaded the script echo `file` and if i have not uploadeda ny image and only text message is set then it echo `both`, i am stuck here since past 4 hours. i don't know ehere my script is wrong or logic is failing. Can anyone help me  with this logic ?

Comment: `print_r($_FILES);` outputs what?

Comment: What is $("#image").val() equal to before you send the AJAX request? Why is you image input named image[]?

Comment: @i-man `image[]` is used to create an array of files named image.

Comment: @bassxzero if file is uploaded it shows `Array
(
    [image] => Array
        (
            [name] => diwali.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\phpAACE.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 581387
        )

)` else it shows `Array()`

Comment: @i-man its blank if nothing selected else it shows file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?php
    if($_GET['id'] == "broadcast")
    {
        $has_message = (isset($_POST['message']) && (strlen(trim($_POST['message'] )) >0));
        $has_file = (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK );

        if( !$has_message && $has_file)
        {
            //file variable is set
            $counter = "file";
        }
        else if( $has_message && !$has_file)
        {
            //message varibale is set
            $counter = "message";
        }
        else if( $has_message && $has_file)
        {
            //both are present
            $counter = "both";
        }
        else {
            $counter = "neither";
        }

        echo $counter;
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: That worked super perfect what was the logic behind it ?

Comment: The error was in your PHP and/or logic, so bassxzero simplified and correct the logic to properly determine if a file was uploaded or a message sent and assigned that to the variables $has_message and $has_file. That way you can test for your 4 cases below with out having to rehash the logic each time.

Answer (score 0):

`isset($_FILES)` is always `true`

`empty($_FILES)` is `true` if there are no files uploaded, otherwise `false`